# How to work with Date and Time in NodeJS, Mongoose and TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I come from the java world and I'm starting in NodeJS.
I'm having a hard time understanding how to work with dates and times in NodeJS.

Only dates and only hours.

Here is an example:

```
export interface teste extends mongoose.Document {
    description: string,
    dateTest: ????,
    openingTime: ????,
    finalTime: ????,
    dateTimeRecord: ????
}

const testeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 200,
        minlength: 3
    },
    dateTest:{
        type: ?????,
        required: true
    },
    openingTime:{
        type: ?????,
        required: true
    },
    finalTime:{
        type: ?????,
        required: true
    },
    dateTimeRecord:{
        type: ?????,
        required: true
    }
}

export const Teste = mongoose.model<Teste>('Teste', testeSchema)
```

In all the places I left ????? I don't know what to put.

- In the dateTest I need to record only dates, without the hours.
- In the openingTime and finalTime I need to store only hours, no dates.
- In the dateTimeRecord I need to store the moment that something happened (date and time).

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose has a `Date` type. [(Docs here)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#dates) Replace the ??? with `Date` and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

in Mongoose you have a type of Date
you can set a default date (Actually it uses ISODate) 
you can code it like this

```
const testeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 200,
        minlength: 3
    },
    dateTest:{
        type: Date,
        default:Date.now // this sets the default date time stamp using proper ISODate format
        required: true
    },
    openingTime:{
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    finalTime:{
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    dateTimeRecord:{
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
}
```

you can read more in the mongoose documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#dates)

Comment: `default: Date.now` will set the date to the time the app starts. You should use `default: () => Date.now` to set it to the time the document was inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Just setting

```js
field {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now
}
```

did not work for me, using typescript. The error pointed out that `Date.now` returns a number while a Date would be expected.

This did the trick:

```js
field {
   type: Date,
   default: () => new Date(Date.now())
}
```